# Does build up in lead pipes make them less dangerous?

Tags: plumbing, water, safety

Maybe this would be more likely in warm water pipes. A place I saw had a super slow warm water tap, which someone with a plumbing background said was from the passageway in the lead pipe decreasing. Would this block lead from getting into the water supply? Though I've read one shouldn't drink from warm water taps anyways, I don't know if enough build up happens in cold taps.

Comment: What sort of buildup? This question is highly theoretical and somewhat vague. Neither are good fits for this site.

Comment: I don't know what type. Maybe it could be from hard water, I don't know. If it would depend on the type of build up then that would be part of the answer. It's not theoretical, I saw a faucet that practically only dripped water coming out, so something decreases the output, either buildup or a pipe expanding somehow. So it may cover what's secreted from the pipe.

Comment: It's like a question of how urgent the safety issue would be.

Comment: It may be the buildup similar to galvanized pipe. When I find lead in my side of the meter I remove it I have since the 70’s. I would not want to take that chance especially if my wife was pregnant or children in the home. I have a friend that moved to angles camp calif the 2 children they had had severe disabilities and and a 3rd that died of SIDS shortly after moving here the rest of there kids are fine I think 7 kids plus a few adopted. So I would not want to mess with lead in drinking water any way and consider is anything other than dangerous to our families.

Comment: The problem with safety is that it's completely subjective. We don't do matters of opinion here because they're essentially popularity contests or recounts of anecdotes. Neither qualify as evidence upon which to base health decisions.

Comment: There are safety levels of things, doesn't sound subjective. That would be like saying there is no point in replacing lead pipes because safety is subjective.

Comment: Have a read: https://cen.acs.org/articles/94/i7/Lead-Ended-Flints-Tap-Water.html

Comment: Can't count on build up to cover lead completely or in all pipes.  Slow water can be caused by a restriction/blockage in just a small section or by faucet strainer being blocked.  Lead in water can be reduced somewhat by running water 5 to 15 minuets before using, stagnant water having more time to pick up lead.

Comment: yes, it does. oxidation is what prevents the lead from freely leaching into the water.

Comment: The reasoning behind not drinking from the hot supply is not one of lead piping, but that a header tank in the attic is not guaranteed to be free of of silt, crud, detritus, dead birds & insects. Climb up & run your hand across the bottom of the tank… guaranteed to cure you of ever wanting to drink from it ever again.

Comment: Why do you even believe you have lead pipes?  Pipes are normally made of iron/steel or copper.  Try a magnet on the pipe - if magnetic it is iron or steel.  Get soapy water and a green Scotchbrite pad and polish the heck out of it - if it comes up orange, it is copper.   *Neither of these are lead*.  Copper is pretty non-reactive, and if iron is leaching into your water, that just brings you closer to your recommended daily *minimum* of iron.  Your body needs iron for blood to work.